# Linq type checking 3 times - is there a better shape?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Linq expression that operates on a list of objects for which one of said objects properties I need to type check before making use of it.

Example:

```
IEnumerable<Employee> activeAuditOwners = (

    from objectStateEntry in objectStateEntries
    where ( objectStateEntry.Entity is IAuditEntity ) == true
       && ( objectStateEntry.Entity as IAuditEntity ).Active == true
    select ( objectStateEntry.Entity as IAuditEntity ).Owner

);
```

My concern is that I use type checking 3 times ( is, as, as ) which doesn't feel very DRY.

Is there a better shape for this query that avoids this (without creating a second query)?

UPDATE: Thanks for the great answers, I have tidied the example a bit for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use the `let` clause:

```
from auditObjectStateEntry in auditObjectStateEntries
let entity = auditObjectStateEntries.Entity as IAuditEntity
where entity != null
   && entity.Active
select entity.Owner
```

Answer (score 3):

What about `OfType` extension method:

```
var data = from a in auditObjectStateEntries.OfType<IAuditEntity>()
           where a.Active
           select a.Owner;
```

Edit:

I overlooked .Entity part so the correct query is:

```
var data = from e in auditObjectStateEntries.Select(a => a.Entity).OfType<IAuditEntity>()
           where e.Active
           select e.Owner;
```

Comment: Sorry Ladislav, my example was misleading - I have updated it. I do not know what the type of objectStateEntry.Entity is - the initial collection is not the problem.

Comment: He wants to filter on the `Entity` property, not the collection itself.

Comment: Ah, yeah, actually OfType is nicer. Forgot about it for a second there. Definitely cleaner than my let suggestion for this! +1

Comment: @svick: Yes I overlooked it but it doesn't mean that `OfType` cannot be used. I added correct query to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are some good solutions here, but I would use `OfType` like this:

```
IEnumerable<Employee> activeAuditOwners = objectStateEntries
  .Select(s => s.Entity)
  .OfType<IAuditEntry>()
  ,Where(e => e.Active)
  .Select(e => e.Owner);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you can use the let expression:

```
from auditObjectStateEntry in auditObjectStateEntries
let auditEntity = auditObjectStateEntry.Entity as IAuditEntry
where auditEntity != null
          &&
      auditEntry.Active
select auditEntry
```

*Update:*
I forgot about `OfType<T>` as suggested by other answerer. Definitely a cleaner solution for this, so recommend using that approach instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can forget the `is`, you don't need it.  Per [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
expression as type
```

is equivalent to:

```
expression is type ? (type)expression : (type)null
```

So you can simplify your code by using a single conversion attempt, perhaps something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Employee> activeAuditOwners = (
    from auditObjectStateEntry in auditObjectStateEntries
    let entity = auditObjectStateEntry.Entity as IAuditEntry
    where entity != null && auditEntry.Active
    select auditEntry.Owner
);
```

Comment: I don't understand, you don't need `as`, so let's use it?

Comment: oi, sorry... don't need to use is.